# Proper way to handle timing after a .append() call in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, append

I have a dynamically-generated table that I append to the page using `.append()`.  I know this is supposed to be instantaneous, but it appears not to be.  Is there a way, or a better way, to stop code execution until the table is rendered on screen?  If I clear the cache and load the page, the highlight divs (which cover the table with a transparent color) are not sized/positioned properly.  Subsequent loads of the page, it works fine.  Here's what I have that's working, but it feels hacky:

```
$('#insert-here').append(tableInsert);

//Even though .append() is "instant," this timeout is necessary to properly size the highlight divs the very first time the page loads.
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.highlight').each(function() {
        $(this).parent().css('position', 'relative');
        $(this).height($(this).prev().find('.info-row').height());
        $(this).width($(this).prev().find('.info-row').width());
        $(this).offset($(this).prev().find('.info-row').offset());
    });
}, 125);
```

Comment: append() is a synchronous call isn't it? Make sure you are calling this code after document.ready

Comment: using a timer to wait for loaded DOM is the worst idea ever.

Comment: I'd be interested to see an MCVE of this, because despite my answer below, I thought with modern browsers, we didn't need to yield back anymore...

Comment: @NickDugger: This isn't about "DOM loaded."

Comment: This is all encased within (function() { //code here })(); - To be honest, I'm not sure what that does, that's how the .js file was when I got to it.  I assumed it's similar to document.ready.

Comment: @Brandon: No, that doesn't do `$(document).ready(...)`. That just gives you a scoping function so the variables within it are not globals (good practice!). What you've probably seen that's a shortcut for `$(document).ready(...)` is `$(function() { /*...*/});`

Comment: I don't think `document.ready` affects me here.  This page is loaded as a module and this particular area of code is within an Ajax request `.done()` function.  The data is pulled from an API as XML, parsed, and turned into a string which contains the HTML markup for the table being inserted.  At this point, I have a large string of HTML being appended, and the `.highlight` class is included there as well as its `.parent()` and `.prev()`.

Comment: @Brandon: Indeed, I don't think this relates to `ready`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements are added to the DOM before `append` returns. What you're seeing is the fact that they haven't been *rendered* yet, so their height/width aren't determined yet.

In my experience, the only way to be sure they've rendered is to let the JavaScript thread yield back to the browser, exactly the way you have done (but the delay can be much shorter; I usually use `0`).

Comment: For this instance, anything less than 125ms yields the same problem.

Comment: @Brandon: Wow, interesting. As I said in a comment, I'd love to see an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for this.

Comment: I didn't know what MVCE stood for.  Give me a few minutes, I'll see if I can whip it up.  This is an excerpt from a very large page.

Comment: Is it possibly because there's more code running after the setTimeout, and that 125ms is allowing the rest of that code to execute before yielding back to the browser?

Comment: @Brandon: No, that code runs anyway, because there is only one main UI thread for JavaScript in browsers. Your JavaScript code cannot interrupt itself (other than a couple of odd quirks in Firefox around `alert` and such). If you do `setTimeout(doSomething, 0);` followed by `doTheNextThing();` and `doAnotherThing();` and so on, you can be **sure** that `doTheNextThing();`, `doAnotherThing();`, and so on run *before* `doSomething` runs. Your browser-based code always runs in response to an *event* (the event may be that the script element was just added to the document *...cont'd...*

Comment: *...continuing...* ...by the HTML parser). Your code runs, single-threaded, until the end of your code, and then that thread returns to the browser's control. The way `setTimeout` works is that when the timer expires, the browser adds an entry to a queue of function calls it's waiting to make when the thread next comes back to it. So if you say `setTimeout(doSomething, 10);` and then your code continues to run for another 250ms, after 10ms browser adds a call to `doSomething` to a queue of calls to make. When your other code finishes and the browser gets the thread back, it looks *cont'd*...

Comment: *...continuing...* at the queue for the oldest outstanding call, and makes that call on the main JavaScript UI thread. The same is true of other events: If your code is actively running when the user clicks a button, the browser queues up the call to your click event handler, and does the call when your code next yields back to the browser.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed description.

I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajv72mko/) that replicates what's going on, except for the fact that it works without the timeout!  Based on your description, I have no idea why I need to set the timer to 125ms.

Comment: @Brandon: Could there be code running in response to a window resize event? It's not uncommon for code responding to window resize to "throttle" itself so that it waits to respond until a brief moment after the last resize event it receives. So if your elements are being sized as a result of that resize code...

Comment: There's no resizing going on.  Come to think of it, the height and width are now set for the table in CSS, and I can do the same with the highlight `div`.  It's not coming out sized wrong on first load, its offset is just off by being 5px too high.  It doesn't happen on subsequent loads of the page, only after clearing the cache.